# Add authenticated/signed attributes with custom oids to PKCS#7 signing?

Tags: cryptography, openssl, pkcs#7

Is there any way to pass extra authenticated attributes for a PKCS#7 signed message using openssl? I'm stuck with the command-line.

I'm currently using :

```
openssl smime -sign -outform DER -md sha1 -binary -signer my.crt -inkey my.key
```

I did not find any releveant option in openssl cli help.

---

More info :

I'm currently trying to build a SCEP (http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/draft-nourse-scep-23.pdf) server in NodeJS.

SCEP spec requires to build PKCS#7 signed `pkiMessages`,

```
The SignerInfo MUST contain a set of authenticatedAttributes (see PKCS#7 [RFC2315] Section 9.2 as well as Section 3.1.1 in this document). All messages MUST contain
* an SCEP transactionID attribute
* an SCEP messageType attribute
* an SCEP senderNonce attribute
* any attributes required by PKCS#7 [RFC2315] Section 9.2 If the message is a response, it MUST also include
```

Currently my only option has been to wrap `openssl` functionality through `child_process.spawn`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to add custom attributes to a signed message from the OpenSSL command line (neither with the smime nor the cms command). If you want to add some custom attributes you will have to use the OpenSSL API.

The main steps are:

- call `CMS_sign` to create a `CMS_ContentInfo`
- create a SignerInfo with `CMS_add1_signer`
- add the attributes to this signer with `CMS_signed_add1_attr_by_OBJ`
- sign with `CMS_final()`

More details here: http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/CMS_sign.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I guess it's time for me to dig into custom NodeJS C++ extensions. Hope I'll survive ;-).